# Ширина блока с width или без

Tags: html, css, width

у меня есть тривиальный вопрос по поводу верстки. Есть такой  код для навигации. Мне из студии заверили что такой подход не правильный надо  `menu` и `social-link` дать 50%  ширины.

**Я хотел бы узнать у вас. Есть какая то разница?**

```
.navigation{
           width:100%;
           padding:15px;
           display:flex;
           justify-content:space-between;
           align-items:center;
           box-sizing:border-box;
}

 .menu{
          display:inline-block;
          padding:15px;
          text-align:center;
          box-sizing:border-box;
   }

.social-link{
          display:inline-block;
          padding:15px;
          text-align:center;
          box-sizing:border-box;
 }

 .link{
       display:block;
       padding-left:15px;
       padding-right:15px;
      }

  .facebook::after{
       content:"facebook";
       font-size:1rem;
       font-family:material-icon;
  }

     .twitter::after{
       content:"twitter";
       font-size:1rem;
       font-family:material-icon;
  }


<nav class="navigation">
     <menu class="menu">
          <a href="" class="link">Home</a>
           <a href="" class="link">About</a>
             <a href="" class="link">Service</a>
                <a href="" class="link">Contact</a>
     </menu>
        <div class="social-link">
           <a href="" class="link facebook">Facebook</a>
           <a href="" class="link twitter">Twitter</a>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: inline-block в 50% ширины будут больше чем 50%

Answer (score 1):

Если их просто вставить как есть, то их ширина будет зависеть от `padding`, в вашем случае ширина будет равна 30px (`padding-left: 15px;` + `padding-right: 15px;`)

```css
.menu {
  background: red;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-link {
  background: blue;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="social-link"></div>
```

Если нужно, чтобы данные блоки были в ширину всего родительского элемента, то люди из студии сказали правильно, что блоки должны иметь `width: 50%`, но т.к. это инлайн блоки, они ещё должны иметь `float: left;` (в связи фичи или бага, хз).

```css
.menu {
  background: red;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-link {
  background: blue;
  
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu, .social-link {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="social-link"></div>
```

Comment: Просто  вопрос в том если добавить  блокам  width: 50%  нужно и задовать  позиционирование для внутренных элементов. Скажем text-align:left; text-align-right; .Получается тоже картина  что и space-between   без  width: 50%. Мне просто  хотелось занть есть разница между  этими  двумя вариантами .